# Populate multi-select with php while loop from db

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, select, populate

The following worked on a local environment. Now that it's pushed
live everything but these seems to work. Displays completely empty select boxes now no checks or blank labels just empty space in the "select options" drop down.
[select display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uopI.png)

```
<?php
  $selected = array();
  $selected = explode(",",$fill['markets']);

  $condb = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `countries`");
  $count = mysql_num_rows($condb);
  $countries = array();
  $str;

  while ($countries = mysql_fetch_array($condb))
  {
    $str = "option{$countries['id']}";
    echo "<option value='{$str}' ";
    if(in_array($str,$selected)) {
      echo "selected>";
      echo $countries['country'];
      echo "</option>";
    } else {
      echo ">";
      echo $countries['country'];
      echo "</option>";
    }
  }      
  ?>
```

Comment: try $countries = mysql_fetch_array($condb); or you can use just a while with: `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {`,

Comment: that's the second variable declared, and it contains the values. $i references the row by id / array element. Since it's an array of arrays it's "arraykey->arrayvalue" in this case row->column.
I know it contains the values because if I echo them specifically/individually it prints them out.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` only returns *one* row at a time, not *all* rows of the result set. Thats why you only have one country listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use while loop instead. You can declare `$i` outside the loop if you need it, Try the following code:

```
  $condb = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `countries`");

  $i = 0;
   while($countries = mysql_fetch_array($condb)) {
    $str = 'option' . $i;
    echo "<option value='{$str}' ";
    if(in_array($str,$selected)) {
      echo "selected>";
      echo $countries['country'];
      echo "</option>";
    } else {
      echo ">";
      echo $countries['country'];
      echo "</option>";
    }
 $i++;
  }
  ?>
</select>
```

**Note:**

`mysql_*` is deprecated as of [php-5.5](/questions/tagged/php-5.5). So instead use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.
[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189)

Comment: don't forget the $i, if you need

Comment: does mysql_fetch_array() automatically go down a row each time you call it within the context of a loop? Will it stop returning at the end of the DB? that's why I chose to use num_rows() with a for loop.

Comment: @RobertWood `mysql_fetch_array()` is a forward only function, so on every run it gets the next row.

Comment: Ah, thanks. So if it returns the last row it returns null after that?

Comment: @RobertWood Yes I suppose or maybe `false`. And if the answer was helpful please accept it.

Comment: Yea sorry, I accepted it. At work atm so it took a moment.